# Create Pairs of number without using catesian in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am new to spark. How can I create pairs in spark.
like below pairs for 4:

```
0,1
0,2
0,3
0,4
1,2
1,3
1,4
2,3
2,4
3,4
```

But without using "cartesain" and it should be executed on cluster.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val nums = sc.parallelize((0 to 4)).flatMap(x => {
  (x to 4).filter(_ > x).map((x, _))
})

println(nums.collect().toList)
//List((0,1), (0,2), (0,3), (0,4), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,3), (2,4), (3,4))
```